# Error in Keras network on IMDB dataset example. Incompatible shapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I believe I have correctly vectorized train and test data, labels, adequate layers, a suitable optimizer, but I cannot understand what is wrong. Why am I getting a ValueError for incompatible shapes?

My code:

```py
from keras.datasets import imdb

(train_data, train_labels),(test_data, test_labels)=imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

import numpy as np

def vectorize_sequences(sequences, dimension=10000):
  results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
  for i, sequence in enumerate(sequences):
    results[i, sequence] = 1.
  return results

x_train = vectorize_sequences(train_data)
x_test = vectorize_sequences(test_data)

def to_one_hot(labels, dimension=46):
  results = np.zeros((len(labels), dimension))
  for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    results[i, label] = 1.
  return results

one_hot_train_labels = to_one_hot(train_labels)
one_hot_test_labels = to_one_hot(test_labels)

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

one_hot_train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
one_hot_test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

from keras import models
from keras import layers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(46, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

x_val = x_train[:1000]
partial_x_train = x_train[1000:]

y_val = one_hot_train_labels[:1000]
partial_y_train = one_hot_train_labels[1000:]

history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val)
```

My error message:

> ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 46) are incompatible

Comment: Can you please show the output from `partial_y_train.head()`? It may not be transforming your labels as you expect.

Comment: sure, it shown me the next: 
ndarray: partial_y_train; ndarray with shape (24000, 1)

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment, if your `partial_y_train` shape is (24000, 1) then that means it has not been one hot encoded correctly. You are using the function `to_one_hot()` in your code, but I dont know what this code is doing. Using Tensorflow's `one_hot` [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot) or [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)'s version would be best, then the shapes should match and the error will be removed.

Comment: I changed my function to_one_hot() to a TensorFlow's one_hot function but still have the same error :c

Comment: Ok, the problem is somewhere else then. If you can, please edit your post to include a subset of your data to make it a minimal reproducible example, so we can run it on our machines and help you better: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example